# Running a Flutter app on an Android phone in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I am coding a Flutter app and I want to run my app on my Android phone but I don't know how to. I am using VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable USB debugging on your phone ([here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable) is how)
2. Connect your phone to the computer
3. `flutter run`

*([here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#set-up-your-android-device) is the official doc about it)*